# MVC Form Validation

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a form that I would like to validate that a field exist in a database. I am currently validating that all fields are in the correct text format etc and posting them to the controller.

The problem being that should the field not exist in the database I am returning the view but the post data is being lost from the form and I am also unaware of how to throw a nice error message explaining what has just happened.

Would anyone know of nice method for preforming some validation on form data within the controller and throwing exceptions messages all while maintaining the form data in the form?

Comment: I would take a look at the Nerd Dinner sample app and documentation. It is a good starting point and covers many of your questions: http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this by simply adding errors to the modelstate stack:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "The new password and confirmation password do not match.");
```

Simples!